# How can I detect a touch of an object in a specific NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have an NSMutableArray filled with different sprites. These sprites are all on the screen.  How can I detect if a touch is landing on one of these sprites, and then do something if a touch on the sprite has occurred?

This is what I have now,

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:_physicsNode];

if(CGRectContainsPoint((starInArray.boundingBox), touchLocation))  {
```

Instead of `(starInArray.boundingBox)`,  I want to be able to say something like `(anyObjectInMyArray.boundingBox)`.

Any way to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for something like that: `for (SKNode *aNode in startInArray){if (CGRectContainsPoint:([aNode frame], touchLocation){//doSomething}}}`?

Comment: Consider keeping a "summary" of the elements of the array that will tell you if a touch *might* have hit the array.  This could be the bounding box, or a checkerboard, or some sort of "ORing" of the locations.  Then you only need to do an element-by-element check in the (hopefully infrequent) case that the touch might have hit.

Comment: @Larme I think that is what I'm trying to accomplish.  I'm still new to Objective-C so I'm not sure how frame works.  Keep in mind - starInArray is just a sprite, not an array.  Would this till work?

Comment: @Alan_s: No, I thought that was pseudo code, and it was an `NSArray`. Look for "for each loop" in Objective-C. Frame may be replace by what you really need, aka a `CGRect`. I don't use SpriteKit, so I just guessed.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should work.

```
  - (BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{

CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touches];    
        for (CCSprite *star in starInArray)
            {
                if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(star.position.x - star.contentSize.width/2,
                                                   star.position.y - star.contentSize.height/2, star.contentSize.width, star.contentSize.height), touchLocation))
                {
                    //Do Something
                    break;
                }
            }
}
```